# CSS background positioning different in safari and firefox

Tags: html, css

I have design a website homepage made of 4 sections. Top, mid1, mid2 and bottom. Each section has a min height of 100% of the web browser. The top section has a transparent background colour with a image/video background.

When the user scrolls down the #videosection should stay behind each section, instead in Safari it does not keep the video section behind the other sections and firefox does not show the video section. Everything is fine using chrome.

HTML:

```
<body>
 <div id="videosection"><video src=""id="bg-video" muted autoplay loop ></video></div>
  <div class="top-section">
  </div> 
  <div class="mid1-section">
        <div id="center-box">
          <section></section>  
        </div> 
  <div class="mid2-section">
    <div class="textbanner"><h3>Design</h3></div>
    <div class="devices box"><img src=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-section">
     <div id="registerform"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
  html, body{
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  min-height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

    #videosection {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0%; 
    left: 0%; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%
    z-index: 1;
    }

    videosection video {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    margin: auto; 
    min-width: 60%; 
    min-height: 50%; }

    .top-section{

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,119,85,0.89), rgba(255,92,106,0.82) ); /* For Safari / background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255,119,85,0.89), rgba(255,92,106,0.82)); / For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 / background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255,119,85,0.89), rgba(255,92,106,0.82)); / For Firefox 3.6 to 15 / background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,119,85,0.89), rgba(255,92,106,0.82)); / Standard syntax */ background-repeat: repeat; 
    position: relative;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%; 
    z-index: 15;}


#center-column {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
margin-top: 10%;
margin-bottom: 5em;
padding: 0;
}

.mid1-section{
  min-height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff5b68;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
    z-index: 15;}

#center-box { 
    overflow: hidden;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;}

.mid2-section{
  min-height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3499dc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
    z-index: 15;}

 .textbanner { 
     overflow: hidden;
     float: none;
     height: 20%;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding-top: 3em;
 }

section { 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ff5b68;
    height: 10.5em;
    width: 40%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 5em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.bottom-section{
  min-height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1ABC9C;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
    z-index: 15;}

#registerform { 
    background-color: #16A085;
    border: 1px solid #16A085;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 420px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 5%;
}
```

Comment: videosection is not valid, do you mean #videosection - sounds like you require to add z-index to your css too, as jmore009 says, need to see the html.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the html, and updated the CSS. I have added a Z-index of 5 to the top, mid and bottom sections and gave the video section a index of 1.

Comment: You have not closed `<div class="mid2-section">`, and your section is not closed either `<section></section  `.

Answer (score 0):

First of, it's better to put the video for last, this will improve the loading of the page.

For making the video stay behind the rest, use `z-index: -1;` in `#videosection`.